# GParted allocation trouble on Win10/Ubuntu dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I have a dual-boot laptop with both Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04.

Currently, the Windows side has too much disk space, and I want to resize things so that the Ubuntu side has more.

Here are my partitions:

[image: gparted partitions]

Any clue for expanding sda7 with unallocated space?

Any help gratefully received.

Comment: Do you want to reduce the size of the Windows partition as well (`sda4`)? or just append the 13.44GiB of the unallocated disk space to `sda7`?

Comment: Thank you @dan 
I want to reduce the size of the Windows partition as well (sda4).
I have reduced the Windows partition, now I have 110.44GiB (unallocated) to append to sd7.

Answer (score 0):

You need the unmounted drives to change the Partition size.  I suggest that you Run an Ubuntu live Version and use gparted from this live Version.

You should resize your Windows Partition first, then move the unallocated space step by step through the partitions until you have reached sda7.

Be carefull and make a Backup of your files. Means both,  Windows and Ubuntu. This Operation can damage your files if something goes wrong.

After the steps above Windows will start maybe in a kind of recovery mode or in a Check Mode -> Check File System

Comment: Thank you!.
Now I have a question. Would it be better to do as you said, or copy sda5 (root)  to a new sda8 at the end and make a new swap and then move and resize sd7 (it will be right next to unallocated space).